# Kinetic email build iOS9 issues

Tags: css, email, html-email

I'm in the process of building a kinetic carousel module for our emails but I'm facing strange issues when viewing it on iOS9 devices, the images within the slides shrink to fit the carousel container or Litmus tests show a 3 and 2 stack of smaller images. Works fine in browsers (obviously) and iOS10 devices. I'm guessing it's a CSS support issue, but I just can't seem to find any details on what is/isn't supported.

[image]

Litmus screen grab for iOS9 iPhone 6+

JS fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ytxmm90b/

```
    <div class="fallback" style="display:block;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x250/4286f4?text=Fallback+Content" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="carouselWrapper" style="display:none; max-height:0; visibility:hidden;">

        <div id="carouselMain">
          <input checked="checked" name="carouselMain" id="slide1" type="radio">
          <input name="carouselMain" id="slide2" type="radio">
          <input name="carouselMain" id="slide3" type="radio">
          <input name="carouselMain" id="slide4" type="radio">

          <div id="carouselSlides">
              <div class="inner">
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x250/4286f4?text=Slide1"> 
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x250/42f4b0?text=Slide2"> </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x250/d15353?text=Slide3"> </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x250/8f3daf?text=Slide4"> </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div id="controls">
            <label for="slide1"></label>
            <label for="slide2"></label>
            <label for="slide3"></label>
            <label for="slide4"></label>
          </div>

        </div>    

    </div>
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .fallback {
        display:none !important;    
    }

    .carouselWrapper {
        display:block !important;
        max-height:none !important;
        visibility:visible !important;
        width:100%;
        max-width:600px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #carouselMain {
        margin: 20px auto;
        width:100%;
        height:250px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #carouselMain input {
        display: none;
    }

    #carouselSlides {
        width:100%;
        height:250px;
    }

    .slide {
        width: 600px;
        height: 250px;
        float: left;
    }

    /* position of image container div to display correct image */
    #slide1:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:0; }
    #slide2:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-100%; }
    #slide3:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-200%; }
    #slide4:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-300%; }

    #carouselSlides div img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* sizes image container */
    #carouselSlides .inner {
        width: 400%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    /* position and dimension of control container */
    #controls {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
    }

    /* dimensions of control buttons. hides that aren't needed for current view*/
    #controls label { 
        display: none;
        width: 5%;
        height: 250px;

    }

    /* Next control - displays label for slide to right of one currently being displayed */
    #slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
    #slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3), 
    #slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4), 
    #slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1) {
        background: url('images/next.png') no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        background-color:#BDBDBD;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    /* Previous control - displays label for slide to left of one currently being displayed */
    #slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
    #slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
    #slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
    #slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3) {
        background: url('images/prev.png') no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        background-color:#BDBDBD;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    /* opacity of controls */
    #controls label:hover {
        opacity:0.9 !important;
    }


    /* Animations */

    /* slide movement */
    #carouselSlides .inner {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
         -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    }

    #carouselMain {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    }

    /* fade effect on controls */
    #controls label {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    }

}

/* Mobile settings us vw units to test out responisivness */

@media screen and (max-width:414px)  {
    .carouselWrapper {
        width:100% !important;
        height: 172px !important;
    }

    #carouselMain {
        width:100% !important;
        height: 172px !important;
    }

    #carouselSlides {
        width:100% !important;
        height:172px !important;
    }

    .slide {
       width: 414px !important;
       height: 172px !important;
    }

    /* postions images inline */
    #slide1:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:0 !important; }
    #slide2:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-414px !important; }
    #slide3:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-818px !important; }
    #slide4:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-1232px !important; }

    /* size images to viewport width */
    .slide img {
        width: 414px !important;
    }

    /* 5x viewport on container div for images*/
    #carouselSlides .inner {
        width: 400% !important;
    }

    /* dimensions of left/right controls - also may need individual queries to control height on different devices */
    #controls {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 172px !important;
    }

    /* dimensions of left/right controls - also may need individual queries to control height on different devices */
    #controls label { 
        width: 5% !important;
        height: 172px !important;   
    }

}

/* SCREEN SIZE SPECIFIC MEDIA QUERIES */

/* iPhone 6/7 */
@media screen and (max-width:375px) {
    .carouselWrapper {
        height: 156px !important;
    }

    #carouselMain {
        height: 156px !important;
    }

    #carouselSlides {
        height:156px !important;
    }

    .slide {
       width: 375px !important;
       height: 156px !important;
    }

    /* postions images inline */
    #slide1:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:0 !important; }
    #slide2:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-375px !important; }
    #slide3:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-750px !important; }
    #slide4:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-1125px !important; }

    /* size images to viewport width */
    .slide img {
        width: 375px !important;
    }

    /* dimensions of left/right controls - also may need individual queries to control height on different devices */
    #controls {
        height: 156px !important;
    }

    /* dimensions of left/right controls - also may need individual queries to control height on different devices */
    #controls label { 
        width: 5% !important;
        height: 156px !important;   
    }       
}

/* iPhone 5 */
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    .carouselWrapper {
        height: 133px !important;
    }

    #carouselMain {
        height: 133px !important;
    }

    #carouselSlides {
        height:133px !important;
    }

    .slide {
       width: 320px !important;
       height: 133px !important;
    }

    /* postions images inline */
    #slide1:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:0 !important; }
    #slide2:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-320px !important; }
    #slide3:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-640px !important; }
    #slide4:checked ~ #carouselSlides .inner { left:-960px !important; }

    /* size images to viewport width */
    .slide img {
        width: 320px !important;
    }
    /* dimensions of left/right controls - also may need individual queries to control height on different devices */
    #controls {
        height: 133px !important;
    }

    /* dimensions of left/right controls - also may need individual queries to control height on different devices */
    #controls label { 
        width: 5% !important;
        height: 133px !important;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Different ios versions have different support for radio buttons as well. it might be a good idea to try and find a device to see if its supporting it.